# Struggling with a simple pySerial implementation

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pyserial

I am new to Python and writing a program to control a servo drive.  All has gone smoothly until I started implementing the serial communications using pySerial.

My Python 3 program calculates the number of revolutions and fractions of a revolution necessary for the servo to move.  I have been testing my work by sending the calculated output to the servo drive using SerialTool Pro under Win 10, through a Waveshare USB to RS-232 module.  A typical byte string sent is b'011001101AF24AD5'.

I used an example from pySerial to set up the port (on a Raspberry Pi 5).  The Pi USB drives the same Waveshare USB to RS-232 module. Code follows.  I get a Tx flicker on the Waveshare but no response from the servo drive.  I suspect that I am making a rookie error.  Any help would be much appreciated.

The port configures fine and the Tx LED flickers on the Waveshare when I send:

```
  ser.flushInput() #Flush receive buffer
  ser.flushOutput() #Flush send buffer

  time.sleep(0.1)

  ser.write(b'011001101AF24AD5')
```

But I get no response reading thus:

```
  time.sleep(0.5)

  numOfLines = 0

  while True:
  rx = ser.readline()
  print("read data: ", rx)
  numOfLines = numOfLines + 1
  if (numOfLines >= 3):
  break
```

I've varied the sleep time and as a last resort slaughtered a goat and placed its entrails on the keyboard.  Nothing but silence.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: If all goes well without pyserial, you can ditch it for opening and configuring the ports yourself.  Ultimately the suspect portion is the port config (baud rate, parity, stop bits, flow control).  Beyond that is always pi power.

Comment: Thanks Abel.  But I'm pretty confident that the port configuration is correct.  I've read the registers and all is good.  I'm really flummoxed by this.

Comment: You can also try gpio, monitoring 5V to the usb device, and ultimately may have to just compare serial with a scope or meter.  That you are writing byte strings at least helps remove endian errors.

Comment: You aren't sending any sort of end-of-line character, so your `.readline()` is going to hang forever (unless you have a timeout set).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Abel.  The problem was the format of the send string.  I was attempting to send the string formatted as hex bytes.  When I stripped that away and sent a pure byte string it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks JasonHarper.  This is an industrial application and I am using Modbus.  The problem proved to be the format of the send strings.